# Why would SerialPort.ReadLine causing an overflow exception?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, stack-overflow, readline

I'm using this line of VB.NET code to read a line of text from a serial port.

```
    Dim incoming As String = MyPort.ReadLine
```

The port is fully initialised and generally working, but sometimes I get an overflow exception and I'm struggling to understand why.

The Microsoft article on [SerialPort.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't list overflow as a possible exception for this command and my (limited) understanding is this normally means you've gone beyond the range of the type, but how does that apply to a string and how should I go about finding the cause of the exception and handling it?

The only current solution I have is catch it in a `Try Catch` block and just writing that it happened in the log file.

Comment: ReadLine method is utter garbage. Starting in .NET 4.5, you can instead call ReadAsync on the BaseStream object, which calls BeginRead and EndRead internally. Basestream and BytesToRead may differ on the number of bytes to read based on the fact that SerialPort classes buffers data, BaseStream doesn't.

Comment: Missing newline character in the stream so buffer overflows? I'd expect that would take quite a while unless you have lots of incoming data.

Comment: @topshot that might do it, in which case I think catch, log, then ignore would be valid.

Comment: Depends on your situation I suppose. I wouldn't normally be ignoring data but maybe you can. If the source normally sent newline, which it must be if you program normally works, I'd be looking at why it stopped. Perhaps when you get the ex, log the buffer and any other properties that might be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: @topshot its old hardware I'm reading the data from so it wouldn't surprise me if it had such quirks.